# Export a list of functions with roxygen2

Tags: r, roxygen2, r-package

**Problem** — I want to export a list of functions as part of an R package, ideally using roxygen2.

To be more precise, I want to export the *functions* in the list, rather than the list itself. For example, consider a list of functions that are generated as closures, like so:

```
addval <- 1:100
fns <- lapply(addval, function(y) {force(y); function(x) x + y})
names(fns) <- paste0("add_", addval)
```

Then the problem is to bind the functions (using the same names in `fns`, for instance) to the package environment, and then include them among the exported functions of the package.

Binding the functions to the package environment can be done easily enough; one way would be

```
for (nm in names(fns)) assign(nm, fns[[nm]])
```

*But is it then possible to use roxygen2 tags to export the functions `add_1`, `add_2`, etc.?*

More to the point: I would like roxygen2 to continue managing the `NAMESPACE` file for me, and would prefer not to have to write `export()` calls, directly. The only way I can see doing that is by writing code to generate boilerplate like

```
#' @export add_1
NULL

#' @export add_2
NULL

# ...
```

or better

```
#' @export
add_1 <- fns[["add_1"]]

#' @export
add_2 <- fns[["add_2"]]

# ...
```

(and forgo the above for-loop).

*Does roxygen2 already have a facility equivalent to such boilerplate generation, or would I have to provide this facility myself?*

I have in mind such a facility being expressed more succinctly as

```
#' @exportObjects names(fns)
NULL
```

where the tag `@exportObjects` would interpret its "argument" as a character vector of names of objects to export.

### Update

roxygen2 6.0.1+ solves this problem with a new `@evalNamespace` tag, which allows you to insert literal entries in the NAMESPACE file:

```
ns_export <- function(nms)
  sprintf("export(%s)", paste(nms, collapse = ","))

#' @evalNamespace ns_export(names(fns))
```

Using the tag `@evalNamespace` is safer than using a `exportPattern()` directive, because in using the latter, one has to be vigilant against accidentally naming an object in the package namespace that matches the regex.

Comment: My deleted answer showed the minimum required items (which you prbly already knew). If you look at the `scales` package, it has many closures and they are all documented by hand.

Comment: @hrbrmstr - Thanks for the suggestion. Could you point me to the appropriate file in `scales`? I have revised the question to make it more to the point and indicate the kind of clumsiness (and extra work) that I would like to avoid.

Comment: So, Hadley (et al) doesn't make them programmatically as you do but [here's a `scales` source file with closures](https://github.com/hadley/scales/blob/master/R/trans-date.r). I don't think you're going to be able to get around manual inclusion in roxygen2.

Comment: @hrbrmstr - Thanks for the pointer! I guess the use-case I've outlined must not be construed common enough to justify it being a part of roxygen2—which would be too bad, since that would make roxygen2 an inadequate (but otherwise fine) tool for documenting a DSL, say, which can be expected to generate lots of user-exposed closures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `@rawNamespace` tag in recent `roxygen2`, this allows using arbitrary syntax valid in a `NAMESPACE` file, including `exportPattern()`:

```
#' @rawNamespace exportPattern("^add_.*$")
```

Comment: This is close enough to what I need, thanks! By the way, where is this tag documented? Ironically, it seems that the documentation for roxygen2 (5.0.1) itself could be a lot better. I did not find a reference to that tag in what seemed to be the likely places (roxygen2's help index and the vignette "Package namespace.")

Comment: @egnha: The [news](https://github.com/klutometis/roxygen/blob/master/NEWS.md) are a good place to look, but the best way to improve documentation is to file an issue or even a pull request on GitHub.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, @krlmlr ! I've submitted a pull request implementing an `exportNames` tag ([#531](https://github.com/klutometis/roxygen/pull/531)).